# Numpy view on 1D array via 2D array as indices range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array which describes index ranges for a 1D array like

```
z = np.array([[0,4],[4,9]])
```

The 1D array

```
a = np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
```

I want to have a view on the 1D array with the index range defined by z. So, for only the first range

```
 a[z[0][0]:z[0][1]]
```

How to get it for all ranges? Is it possible to use as_strided with unequal lengths defined by z as shape? I want to avoid to copy data, actually I only want a different view on a for further computation.

Comment: Because of the irregular window lengths, don't think this would be possible.

Comment: So, what's wrong with `a[z[0][0]:z[0][1]]`, `a[z[1][0]:z[1][1]]` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [66]: a = np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
In [67]: z = np.array([[0,4],[4,9]])
```

So generating the slices from the rows of `z` we get 2 arrays:

```
In [68]: [a[x[0]:x[1]] for x in z]
Out[68]: [array([1, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
```

Individually those arrays are views.  But together they aren't an array.  The lengths diff, so they can't be `vstacked` into a (2,?) array.  They can be `hstacked` but that won't be a view.

The calculation core of `np.array_split` is:

```
sub_arys = []
sary = _nx.swapaxes(ary, axis, 0)
for i in range(Nsections):
    st = div_points[i]
    end = div_points[i + 1]
    sub_arys.append(_nx.swapaxes(sary[st:end], axis, 0))
```

Ignoring the `swapaxes` bit, this is doing the same thing as my list comprehension.

Comment: Then I could also use split directly with the change points as splitting points, in this case np.split(a, [4,9]). The question is what is faster? I think split copies the data, so the for loop with the ranges is faster?

Comment: np.split returns sub-arrays (_view_, in this context). If `b = np.split(a, [4, 9])` and  `a[1] = -1`, then `b[0][1] == -1`

Answer (score 1):

```
for x, y in z:
    array_view = a[x:y]
    # do something with array_view
```